# Gradle dependecies cache may be corrupt in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

```
Error:Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.registerTransform(Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/gradle/api/Action;)V'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

    Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
    Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

    The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
    Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)

Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
```

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Comment: Have you tried disabling plugins?

Comment: @MichaelVescovo not yet !

Comment: Try it out and let me know if it works....

Comment: @MichaelVescovo thanks bro ! its working !

Comment: Ok great. I moved my comment to an answer. Please accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling plugins, since it mentions there may be one that is incompatible.